# is it possible to clone a multimethod?

Tags: clojure

I wish to be able to take a multi-method, clone it as a seperate variable and add to it without changing the original. How can this be done?

```
(defmulti hello :type)

(defmethod hello :a
  [e] (assoc e :a 1))

(hello {:type :a})
=> {:type :a :a 1}

;; my attempt at cloning
(def world @#'hello)

(defmethod world :b
  [e] (assoc e :b 2))

(world {:type :b})
=> {:type :b :b 2}

;; I want this to throw... but because `hello` and `world` 
;; are the same function, it still works
(hello {:type :b})
=> {:type :b :b 2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out by looking at https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1769-L1777:

```
(defn clone
  [multi name]
  (let [table (.getMethodTable multi)
        clone (clojure.lang.MultiFn. name 
                                     (.dispatchFn multi) 
                                     (.defaultDispatchVal multi)
                                     (.hierarchy multi)]
    (doseq [[dispatch-val method] table]
      (.addMethod clone dispatch-val method))
    clone))
```

---- back to the original question ----

```
(defmulti hello :type)

(defmethod hello :a
  [e] (assoc e :a 1))

(def world (clone hello "world"))

(defmethod world :b
  [e] (assoc e :b 2))

(world {:type :b})
=> {:type :b :b 2} 

(hello {:type :b})
=> (throws)
```